# unable to save data in different tables in ror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

i am trying to save data into different tables using a single form.I have two models.i.e A and B.I am trying to store the attributes of B using the A form.My A model is:

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
has_one :B
accepts_nested_attributes_for :B
end
```

My B model is:

```
class B < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :A
end
```

My A controller is:

```
class AController < ApplicationController

def index
    @a = A.all

end 

def new
    @a = A.new
end

def create
    @a = A.new(a_params)
    @a.b.build
    if @a.save
        redirect_to a_path
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

private 

def a_params
    params.require(:a).permit(:name, :age, :address :b => [:fname, :phone])
end
end
```

my new.html.erb is:

```
<%= form_for(:a, url:  a_path)  do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %>
    <%= f.text_field :age%>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address%>
</div>

<%= f.fields_for :b do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :fname, "father name" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :fname %>
  </p>
      <p>
      <%= f.label :phone, "phone" %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
   <% end %>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I am unable to store data in both tables.i.e..the data entered is stored in A table but failed to store in B table.

Comment: please check my answer, it's working or not

Comment: please check this repo code https://github.com/chaudharyprakash/nested_attributes

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things seem wrong:

1) You're not using strong parameters correctly , it should be

```
   params.require(:a).permit(:name, :age, :address, :b_attributes => [:fname, :phone])
```

2) You can remove

```
    @a.b.build
```

The association and saving of b record should be done for you by rails at once.

Comment: i have changed  to    params.require(:a).permit(:name, :age, :address, :b_attributes => {:fname, :phone}).but there is an error saying: Unpermitted parameter:b

Comment: perhaps try :b_attributes=> [:fname, :phone]

Answer (score 0):

```
The build method signature is different for  has_one and
```

The build syntax for has_many association:

```
@a.b.build
```

The build syntax for has_one association:

```
@a.build_b  # this will work

@a.b.build  # this will throw error




class AController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @a = A.all

    end 

    def new
        @a = A.new
    end

    def create
        @a = A.create(a_params)
        @a.build_b
        if @a.save

          redirect_to a_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private 

    def a_params
        params.require(:a).permit(:name, :age, :address, :b_attributes => [:fname, :phone])
    end
end
```

it's working fine in my local machine.

Comment: thanks for the reply but its not working..i am facing unpermitted parameter error..